# hyperledger fabric orderer build failed with 2 error

Tags: build, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

followed build instructions from https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/dev-setup/devenv.html. please let me know how to resolve the errors while building. I have installed all the prerequisites, in ubuntu, I am getting the following error.

Building build/bin/orderer
GOBIN=/home/cdac/go/src/github.com/harishgithubb/fabric/build/bin go install -tags "" -ldflags "-X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.Version=2.5.0 -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.CommitSHA=2f2e5aa3f -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseDockerLabel=org.hyperledger.fabric -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.DockerNamespace=hyperledger" github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/orderer

## runtime/internal/sys

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/consts.go:13:7: StackGuardMultiplier redeclared in this block
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/arch.go:27:74: previous declaration
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/consts.go:16:7: DefaultPhysPageSize redeclared in this block
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/arch.go:36:29: previous declaration
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/consts.go:20:7: PCQuantum redeclared in this block
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/arch.go:40:19: previous declaration
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/consts.go:23:7: Int64Align redeclared in this block
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/arch.go:43:20: previous declaration
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/consts.go:30:7: MinFrameSize redeclared in this block
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/arch.go:50:22: previous declaration
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/consts.go:34:7: StackAlign redeclared in this block
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/arch.go:54:20: previous declaration
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/stubs.go:9:7: PtrSize redeclared in this block
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/arch.go:24:38: previous declaration
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/stubs.go:10:24: undefined: Uintreg
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/stubs.go:16:7: StackGuardMultiplier redeclared in this block
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/consts.go:13:77: previous declaration
Makefile:227: recipe for target 'build/bin/orderer' failed
make: *** [build/bin/orderer] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes when the previous version is not removed properly and on top of previous version new version is installed. Try doing a clean installation of go again , removing the current version completely.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.